# how to display 2 decimal point in a double

Tags: c#, double

I want to show a 2 decimal point for the Average in the console.WritLine. Right now it showing a whole number.

```
string input = "";
int total=0 ;
int numbersEntered =0 ;
double average=0.00 ;

total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
numbersEntered++;
average = (total / numbersEntered);
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2:#.##}\t", total, numbersEntered, average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You might want to read some documentation first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Math.Round(average,2)

Answer (score 2):

declare `total` and `numbersEntered` double as well. you are using int, then dividing integer with integer will return whole number not a double with 2 decimal point.

```
string input = "";
double total=0 ;
double numbersEntered =0 ;
double average=0.00 ;

total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
numbersEntered++;
average = (total / numbersEntered);
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2:#.##}\t", total,    numbersEntered, average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is C#?  You probably want to add the tag to get better answers.  If it is, try replacing your `Console.WriteLine` with this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2:F2}\t",
                   total, numbersEntered, average);
```

The documentation I found for this was [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
average = (total / numbersEntered);
```

to

```
average = ((double)total / numbersEntered);
```

The operator `/` between two integers does integer division. Only after the division is performed is the result (quotient) converted from `int` to `double`, but by then precision has already been lost.

I converted one of the operands (the left one) from `int` to `double`; the right operand will then automatcally be converted as well (the conversion from `int` to `double` is implicit). When the operands of the `/` operator are `double`s, floating-point division is performed which is what you want.